# How to select date from date picker ion selenium web driver?

Tags: java, testing, selenium, automation, webdriver

What is the code for selecting the date from date picker in selenium web driver ?
We tried a lot on java selenium web driver codings

![Selenium Codings for Web driver]
 [https://i.stack.imgur.com/15gdR.png]

Find the  below attached screen shots

Comment: We will probably need to see the page to help, unlike say on a mobile device date pickets on websites are custom things and have no standard to be able to select them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Click on the Joining Date field and click on required date like

```
driver.findElement(By.<Joining Date field>).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText(<Date>)).click();
```

Ex:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("calendarSelect")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("6")).click();
```

Comment: Above code not works for me...
There is no such link text exist in Inspecting Element

Comment: Can you show us, what HTML is showing (or) give us a link for that calender

Answer (score 0):

Use Absolute xpath, just use firebug to identify the date of that datepicker and right-click to get xpath, and use that xpath to select that element

Comment: Usage of absolute auto-generated xpath doesn't have any advantage and makes code fragile. It's easiest but not right solution in such situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its never fails

`try{

```
    WebElement dateWidget = driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(object)));

    List<WebElement> rows = dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));  
    List<WebElement> columns = dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("td"));  

    for (WebElement cell: columns){
        if (cell.getText().equals(data)){
            cell.findElement(By.linkText(data)).click();
            break; 
        }
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    return Constants.KEYWORD_FAIL+" -- Not able to select the date"+e.getMessage();
}`
```